# Maximal number of edges of connected graph of fixed genus?

Tags: graph-theory

For a connected graph with edges $E$ and vertices $V$ we consider the topological genus, which can be computed as $g=|E|-|V|+1$. Fixing a genus $g$, what is the maximal number of edges that a connected leafless graph of genus $g$ can have? Is there a classification those graphs realizing the maximum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to decide whether you want to allow vertices of degree 2. If you do that you can draw a circle and place arbitrarily many vertices on it. This gives you a graph of genus $1$. You can adapt the construction slightly for higher genus.

If you don't allow vertices of degree $2$, together with the leafless condition, each vertex has degree at least $3$. This gives the constraint $E \ge \frac{3}{2}V$. If you fix $g$ this gives you an inequality for $V$.